# Accessing nodejs cookies in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies

I am building a simple web app using nodejs as backend with angularjs front-end.

With nodejs I am setting some cookies after a user logs in.

```
res.cookie(name,value)
```

I am creating two cookies each for username and user_id.
and when I see the set cookies, using

```
res.json(req.cookies)
```

and the json response have the actual user_id and also with a another key 
**connect.sid**, maybe because I am using connect-flash, I don't know.

But when I access the cookies in angularjs using $cookies.get('user_id')
the value is some encoded value,

For eg : 
for actual user_id : **571be8d34666cf69664645d5**,

I am getting    **j%3A%22571be8d34666cf69664645d5%22**

How can I get the actual userid ?

I know that the real ID is in between the string and I can get it by using some string manipulation, but is there another way.

I am using passportjs, express-session, connect-flash, connect-mongo,cookie-parser in my app.

Comment: where does the `value` come from? Is it an object?

Comment: I am setting the value using req.user._id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two different cookies, you can set the object in the cookie from express, and on angular side you can get the cookies by:

```
$cookies.getObject('cookiename',object)
```

In your case either write a function for splitting the cookie or use `JSON.parse(json)` for parsing the cookie coming from express.
I did it other way round and managed to read the cookie object in express by `JSON.parse(cookieobj.user_id)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that as of angular 1.4, you should use `$cookies.getObject('user_id')` for deserialize version of the value. Start with that, if not a solution, check on the console the actual value of the cookie to try to understand where the `j:"571be8d34666cf69664645d5"` come from.

Comment: I looked in the angular docs and tried that already, its giving me an error : Unexpected token j in JSON at position 0. On the console, document.cookie is also giving me the same value. And I can't understand where is this coming from, as the username cookie is intact.